# How to map through an array inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript object that contains an array:

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: "Loop through an array",
    tags: ["array", "map", "foreach"]
}
```

I map through the object using:

```
{snippets && snippets.map(snippet => (
    <p key={snippet.id}>{snippet.title}</p>
))}
```

However, I can't seem to map through the 'tags' array inside the object. What would be the correct syntax to do this, please?

Comment: Is the object in the question one of the objects of the `snippets` array? What is the expected html structure for `tags` array?

Comment: The same way as you do for the snippets. You just use `snippet.tags.map(...)`

Comment: Hi Adiga, sorry, I might be getting my terms mixed up. I need to loop through the tags in the first code excerpt, probably in a <ul>

Comment: seems you aree getting down votes because your question is not quite clear.

Could you specify what snippets in this case is? Is it the object you placed? You cant iterate through an object like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to `map()` on `snippet.tags` like this :

```js
const snippets = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Loop through an array",
    tags: ["array", "map", "foreach"]
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: "Loop through another array",
    tags: ["foo", "bar", "ham"]
}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    {snippets.map(snippet => (
        <p key={snippet.id}>
          <div>
            <strong>{snippet.title}</strong>
          </div>
          
          {snippet.tags.map(tag => (
            <button>{tag}</button>
          ))}
        </p>
      ))}
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is no native map method for object, but we can do like this:**

```
let snippets ={
    'id': 1,
    'title': "Loop through an array",
    'tags': ["array", "map", "foreach"]
};

Object.keys(snippets).map((key, index)=> {
    console.log(index);         // 0,1,2
    console.log(key);          // id, title, tags
    console.log(snippets[key]); // 1, Loop through an array, ["array", "map", "foreach"]
});
```

**another way that we can easily iterate over an object using "for...in"**