# unable to map through array when nested inside object

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript

The closest link I've read for the question I'm trying to solve is this one.

[Map through an array inside an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145151/how-to-map-through-an-array-inside-an-object)

I have an object with a prop called clients. The data type of clients is an array.

I get the error

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, props, key, ref, __k, __, __b, __e, __d, __c, __h, constructor, __v, __source, __self}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Intellisense tells my the type is an array of objects
[image: Type from intellisense])

I'm very confused about this one, I don't usually have this kind of trouble. I'm using Preact and Compat, which may be causing some further complications.

- Node: v18.13.0
- NPM: 8.19.3
- "preact": "^10.15.0"
- "@preact/compat": "^17.1.2"

Here's the code:

```
export const clientData = {
  clients: [
    {
      name: 'comapany1',
      logo: './src/assets/images/company1.png',
    },
    {
      name: 'company2',
      logo: './images/company2.png',
    },
    {
      name: 'company3',
      logo: './images/company3.png',
    },
    {
      name: 'company4',
      logo: './images/company4.png',
    },
    {
      name: 'company5',
      logo: './images/company5.png',
    },
  ],
};
```

Whenever I try to map over this, I get an error. I have tried the following:

```
clientData?.clients?.map(client => {
            return (
              <div class="mt-12 grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-5 md:grid-cols-5">
                <div class="p-4 grayscale transition duration-200 hover:grayscale-0">
                  <img src={client.logo} class="h-32 w-auto mx-auto" loading="lazy" alt="client logo" width="" height="" />
                  <p class='text-center pt-5' >{client.name}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          })
```

I've also tried

```
const { clients } = clientData;       

 {
          clients.map(client => {
// ...
      }
        }
```

Last thing I tried

```
 {
          Array.isArray(clients) &&
            clients.map(client => {
              return (
                <div class="mt-12 grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-5 md:grid-cols-5">
                  <div class="p-4 grayscale transition duration-200 hover:grayscale-0">
                    <img src={client.logo} class="h-32 w-auto mx-auto" loading="lazy" alt="client logo" width="" height="" />
                    <p class='text-center pt-5' >{client.name}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sure Ken, this is the first time someone has flagged this as an issue. I'm surprised because having read the thread it looks like a big no-no. Will bear in mind.

Comment: Your first approach works fine. Here's a [sandbox using your example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-roentgen-54ukg7?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thanks. I've found the culprit, it was the react-slick module. Weird because it worked fine for half an hour and I've no idea why it broke...